# Installing multiple versions of R

Tags: linux, r

When I was in school the system administrator had multiple versions of R installed. I'm running into a bug with R-3.1.0 and need to install reinstall some past versions of R for development while this bug is investigated, but I don't see any documentation about how to have multiple concurrent versions of R on the same system  ti should look something like

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib | grep R-
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root         8 Jun  3 09:41 R -> R-3.1.0/
drwxr-xr-x  9 root  root      4096 May 15 11:56 R-3.1.0
drwxr-xr-x  9 root  root      4096 May 15 11:56 R-3.0.3


$ ls -l /usr/bin | grep R-
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  root         8 Jun  3 09:41 R -> R-3.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x  9 root  root      4096 May 15 11:56 R-3.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x  9 root  root      4096 May 15 11:56 R-3.0.3
```

I see no documentation about how to achieve this either in the [R Installation and Administration](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html) guide or in the `configure --help`.  I'm running a Gentoo system and the ebuild removes or overwrites the previous version of R on install, so I'll likely be installing from source.

Comment: [Use `configure --prefix`, or `make prefix=...`](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installation)

Comment: Someone recently shared a tool with me that is specifically for this, https://github.com/viking/Renv, but I'd just tend towards Dirk's approach.

Comment: This more recent (Feb 2020) RStudio support blog post might be helpful as well [Installing multiple versions of R on Linux](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/215488098-Installing-multiple-versions-of-R-on-Linux)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is pretty easy as Josh Ulrich's comment already says.

People usually have this question regarding r-devel installation alongside the basic R you will get from your distro.  I use a simple shell script to build / update R-devel, and two matching ones to run R-devel and Rscript-devel.  I can't recall if I blogged about it, but folks seem to point to an this older post on the r-sig-debian list which contains it. [Here is a nice post by Michael](http://www.personal.psu.edu/mar36/blogs/the_ubuntu_r_blog/2012/08/installing-the-development-version-of-r-on-ubuntu-alongside-the-current-version-of-r.html) detailing the same process.

And by creating new subdirectories, you can add as many R version as you want.  You should keep the local builds in `/usr/local`, though, and could create softlinks for the binaries in `/usr/local/bin`. The script `R` itself will have `R_HOME_DIR` hard-coded and "just work".

Fancier approaches involve virtualization, and on Linux your best bet is [docker](http://www.docker.io) which I am playing with now, and which I hope to detail at some point for this very purpose of testing R packages against multiple compilers etc.

Comment: Thanks Dirk.  I don't need anything that complicated. It's just that the parser data for R-3.1.0 is messed up and giving bad results.  I need to install 3.0.3 until Duncan has a chance to look at and fix it.  So do I just use --prefix=/usr/local/R-3.0.3 and then there's some linking that I have to do.

Comment: To anyone reading I would recommend also the guide from [Rstudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/215488098-Installing-multiple-versions-of-R)

Comment: did you ever write anything up about the docker usage dirk?

Comment: Not a formal tutorial as far as I can remember -- but if you look _e.g._ at the [`.travis.yml` for Rcpp](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/.travis.yml) it constructs a matrix using multiple R versions via multiple Docker containers.

Comment: This is no longer accessible ' Here is a nice post by Michael '

Comment: Well I wrote that nine years ago.  Sometimes the internet does not provide time-stable links.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I understand that. Could you please share links to other similar content that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on R but on Linux you can always use schroot and debootstrap to create a new isolated environement with different versions of R, libraries, ... Actually I use it to compile different versions of code for RedHat, Ubuntu or Debian.

See for example: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebootstrapChroot

(Once you get use to it, it will take no more than 20 minutes to create a new chrooted system)