# Is there a way to install R version 3.3.0 on ubuntu?

Tags: r, ubuntu, installation

I need version 3.3.0 of R for a project but up until now I have not succeeded. I want it to work for my Rstudio, but I have not found anyway to install this older version and then override the R version that my Rstudio is using now. How can I get all this done?

I used the 3.3.0 version from https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/, it is installed but Rstudio does not use it. After executing 'make' it doesn't give any errors, but it doesn't seem to work since Rstudio remains on version 3.4.4.

I expected it to run easily, but I cannot figure out how to stop version 3.4.4 from showing up and instead use 3.3.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing multiple versions of R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019503/installing-multiple-versions-of-r)

Comment: R-studio does not come embedded with R base. This means that if you install R base you will have the same version, despite if you enter R from terminal or Rstudio.

What could happen is that you have installed R twice which has given you 2 version. If you just need one R base version, I recommend you to totally uninstall R-base and after that attempt to install the R base you need.

Comment: You need to configure RStudio to use the other version. Look in its Global Options menu.

Comment: Interestingly I do NOT see the option to change the R version in the global options menu, section "R General" on my Ubuntu 18.04 system. The Windows version of RStudio does give me this option. Perhaps just because I have only one installed R version?

Comment: @RYoda It might not be there. I don't use Ubuntu regularly and if I do it's usually with RStudio Server. But I'm quite confident that OP needs to (and can) configure RStudio to use a different R version.